# Probability Proof: Same Probability in Coin Toss

Tags: probability

Given a fair coin, suppose that the first friend flips the coin $k$ times and the second friend flips the coin $n-k$ times. How can we prove that the probability that both friends flip the same number of heads is the same as the probability that there are total of $k$ heads?

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1,2$ let $H_i$ denote the number of heads and let $T_i$ denote the number of tails thrown by friend $i$.

Then $\langle H_1,H_2\rangle$ and $\langle T_1,H_2\rangle$ have equal distributions so that:
$$P(H_1+H_2=k)=P(T_1+H_2=k)=P(k-H_1+H_2=k)=P(H_1=H_2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.  Match sequences of flips where they have the same number of heads with sequences where the second friend's flips remain the same and the first friend's flips were all the reverse of what they had been.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that there are a total of $k$ heads is simply ${n\choose k}2^{-n}$, so it is enough to determine the probability that the friends get the same number of heads.

Due to the symmetry of the problem, we may assume that $k\leq n-k$. Then the probability that the friends get the same number of heads is
$$ 2^{-n}\sum_{l=0}^k{k\choose l}{n-k\choose l}=2^{-n}\sum_{l=0}^k{k\choose k-l}{n-k\choose l}=2^{-n}{n\choose k}$$
by Vandermonde's identity. Therefore the two probabilities are the same.